# Shoulder Rod Stretch, Trying to gain flexibility and reached a limit

Tags: exercise, stretching, flexibility, yoga, gymnastics

I am doing the following shoulder rod dislocation stretch. I seemed to have reached a cap on how far I can put my hands together. Right now they are 40 inches apart, at 30 degree from vertical. I was making progress for first few months, then after that, it became harder to gain flexibility.

What can I do to improve the stretch like this person below?

https://youtu.be/IWDN-RW-at8?t=239

[image]

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this important to you?

Comment: hi @DarkHippo I do gymnastics and tumbling